# MSSQL 2012-19 Server Audit will not DROP, Recreates minutes later

Tags: sql, sql-server, audit

Previous teammate created a SQL Server Audit on of our production systems that records Successful and Failed attempts to log in.

It is not a bad idea but they had it running to the Servers Security Log, and it overwrites multiple times a day.

I have tried to remove it signed is 'sa', signed into DAC, impersonating the teammate, disabling before deleting, deleting specs first, deleting audit first, delete and reboot....it just keeps coming back 20-30 minutes later

I cannot locate any trigger or database with a seprate set of audit specs.
Yesterday I attempted to use profiler to trace where the trigger to recreate is coming from but had no luck.

```
-- remove server audit
USE [master]
GO
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [Stupid_Audit]
 WITH (STATE = OFF)
GO

USE [master]
GO
DROP SERVER AUDIT [Stupid_Audit]
GO


-- remove server audit specification
USE [master]
GO
ALTER SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Stupid_AuditSpec]
 WITH (STATE = OFF)
GO

USE [master]
GO
DROP SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Stupid_AuditSpec]
GO
```

Here is what I saw in Profiler

```
sql_batch_starting 
event_sequence 86477
database: master
Login: service account running SQL   

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    
    CREATE SERVER AUDIT [Stupid_Audit] TO SECURITY_LOG
    WHERE [action_id] = (1397311308)
        AND NOT [additional_information] LIKE '%<pooled_connection>1</pooled_connection>%'
        OR [action_id] = (1179207500)
        AND [additional_information] LIKE '%<error>0x00004818</error>%';
    
    CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Stupid_Audit_AuditSpec]
    FOR SERVER AUDIT [Stupid_Audit] ADD (FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP)
        ,ADD (SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN_GROUP)
    WITH (STATE = ON);
    
    ALTER SERVER AUDIT [Stupid_Audit]
        WITH (STATE = ON);
```

***Update:*** No Server Task, no Trigger, no Stored Procedures, no Jobs referencing

Profiler listed user as the service account
and it was in Master

Comment: There's probably a SQL Server Agent job or Scheduled Task to ensure the audit isn't deleted by an attacker. If your security log is too small to hold an entire day's entries you should *increase its size*, not set it to overwrite older entries. An attacker would have to successfully connect to the server before accessing the database. Don't you want to know what else they may have done?

Comment: I have setup another that creates a file in a central location for our security to review.
I just want this old one gone so the server can have its Security log back.

Thank you for the feedback

Comment: Did you check for any SQL Server Agent jobs or Windows Scheduled Tasks? Something with a schedule of 20-30 minutes? It may be just a step in a larger script that runs every 20 minutes

Comment: In SQL Server Profiler and Extended Events you can see the account that executes a command, the machine name that issued the command and even the application's name

Comment: No Server task, no Trigger, no stored procedure.
I looked for a job and none with the keywords

Comment: If memory serves, the audit will audit operations against itself. At the very least, audit start/stop events. I'd look for who (and possibly where) the audit start is running as as a clue to how this is getting re-created.

Answer (score 0):

I should have mentioned it was SqlThreatDetection_Audit.
It was the Azure log analytics agent and had to shut it off in Azure Cloud Defender.

Good luck to the rest of the world.

SOLVED